# 404 Can't refer url to page code codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to refer to my page v_input from v_home with href and always get 404 page. I've already check the controller name and function, default route, and default controller. I search this error for many hours and got no result. Here my code

routes

```
route['default_controller'] = 'c_home';
```

config

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sispak/';
```

this is url that i referring to v_input

v_home

```
 <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
            <h4>Sistem Pakar</h4>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('/c_home/input'); ?>">Input Data</a></li>

            </ul><br>
        </div>
```

this is the controller 
c_home

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');

class c_home extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('M_home');
    $this->load->model('M_kalkulasi');
}

public function index() {
    $data['dataKualitasAir'] = $this->M_home->readListAir();
    $this->load->view('v_home', $data);
}

public function input() {
    $this->load->view('v_input');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your file name

```
C_home.php
```

And

```
class C_home extends CI_Controller {

  // code
}
```

File and Class names must begin with first letter only upper case.

User Guide Controller http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

User Guide Model http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model

And change this

```
<?php echo base_url('/c_home/input'); ?>
```

To removing the first /

```
<?php echo base_url('c_home/input'); ?>
```